# Responsive issue with Material UI Pagination Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on implementing a Material UI Pagination component in my project, and I'm facing responsiveness issues when the screen size changes. I've provided images to illustrate the problem:

1. Full-screen view:

   [image: This is how it currently looks on full screen]
2. This is how it currently looks on smaller screens:

   [image: This is how it currently looks on smaller screens]
3. This is how it's supposed to look on smaller screens:

   [image: This is the intended outcome]

This is my code:

Pagination.tsx:

```
import { ChangeEvent, FC } from 'react'
import { StyledPagination, StyledPaginationItem } from './Pagination.styles'
import { PaginationProps } from './component'
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack'
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward'

const MuiPagination: FC<PaginationProps> = ({ onChange, size = 'extraLarge', ...args }) => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'))

  const handleChange = (_: ChangeEvent<unknown>, value: number) => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isSmallScreen ? (
        <StyledPagination count={10} />
      ) : (
        <StyledPagination
          siblingCount={0}
          boundaryCount={1}
          {...args}
          size={size}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default MuiPagination
```

This is my styling file:

Pagination.styles.ts:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import MuiPagination from '@mui/material/Pagination'
import MuiPaginationItem from '@mui/material/PaginationItem'

export const StyledPagination = styled(MuiPagination)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',

  '.MuiPagination-ul > li': {
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0.5),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
  },
}))

export const StyledPaginationItem = styled(MuiPaginationItem)(({ theme }) => ({}))
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions you can provide to make the Material UI Pagination component responsive across different screen sizes.

Thank you in advance for your help!